# Process incoming network json objects

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to process some incoming json traffic such as this:
[image: incoming network traffic json]

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do that in an extension (for personal use mainly, as a debug tool). Ideally I'd like to have a function in the spirit of void Process( object jsonObject ). Is there any way to do that?

I have tried to look for a way to achieve this simple functionality (by looking for event listeners, extensions development, ...) with no success.

EDIT : 
When developing a chrome content script extension, how can I listen to the network events on a page (for example, the ones shown above) in the content script file?

Comment: What is this `Process()` function you mention?

Comment: By that I mean being able to implement a listener/function that will have as an argument the content that I can access (which is a httpResponse in the form of a json object)

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are actually asking here. Do you have code which is already requesting this data and want to process it? Is it just some random request that is being made by some web page that you are wanting access to the data? Is it a specific web page where you are wanting to intercept the data prior to it being returned to the web page? What *exactly* are you wanting?

Comment: I am trying to access the payload from a request from a particular website.  whilst navigating, in either an extension or within the developer tools, and have the possibility to write my own handler for it

Comment: (I should precise that the data is being requested through normal use of chrome, and that it's unimportant when I get access to it). In more simple terms, I want to be able to have either an extension or a developer tool processing the data chrome is receiving to extract information.

Answer (score 1):

You can start using [WebRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) from chrome extensions API.
Using filters you can set what exactly you want to observe. But it helps only to collect needed urls, because the API doesn't allow to get direct access to a response body.
To get a body you need to make a new request from a chrome extension.